# sonar new line coverage metric for C#

Tags: c#, sonarqube, metrics

We have no following metrics into History table in sonar:

1. New Coverage
2. New line coverage
3. New lines to cover

Other metrics are collected, as Code coverage, Coverage on new code, etc.

Could you please suggest:

What should be add to configuration to enable with metrics? and if it is possible, is it described anywhere how exactly with metrics (New Coverage, New line coverage, New lines to cover) collected and calculated?

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate the [Sonar C# Gallio Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/sonar-csharp-gallio-plugin) in order to get those metrics. This plugin will launch the projects that contain unit tests and will report the metrics in Sonar. You can take a look at this example application to see how it works: https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-dotnet/tree/master/tools/dotnet-tools-commons/src/test/resources/solution/Example

As for the metric meaning, you can check the following page to know more: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Java+Metric+Definitions#JavaMetricDefinitions-Tests